# Symfony - set entity field as timestamp

Tags: php, symfony, timestamp

In my Symofny project I want for my entity to have `timestamp` field.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $timestamp;

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function setTimestamp()
{
    $this->timestamp = new DateTime("now");
    return $this;
}
```

I want to be saved in timestamp format? How can I accomplish that?
Like ***// => 1387909800***

I am on Symfony 4.3 version.

Comment: Why would you want it saved as a timestamp? If you need the timestamp, you can easily get it from the `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [getTimestamp();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $timestamp;

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function setTimestamp()
{
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $this->timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    return $this;
}
```